# Android app: SSH Cisco switch to get active connections

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm new here and in need of a bit of help. I'm looking to create an app for an Android tablet that is connected via ethernet to a CISCO switch.

I have some CISCO SSH commands to check status of ports (16 in total), and if they are active I would like to show a green light on the screen next to a label for expected device.

Can someone guide me on the best way to implement this as I'm struggling to find any examples on the web.

Many thanks
Jon

Answer (score 0):

In a standalone Java app, I would typically use [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/%20JSch) for this.  I know you can start a [shell session](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Shell.java.html) from it against most Cisco routers, hopefully switches too.

I've not tried JSch under Android, though [this blog tip](http://eridem.net/android-tip-021-ssh-execute-remote-commands-with-android) suggests it can be done.